# Javascript ternary operator not working inside input tag

Tags: javascript

I have javascript which returns true / false which eventually determines whether a checkbox will be checked or not.

Below are the code. But is is not behaving as expected. This code sets profiles value to checked instead of being a attribute value. Could you please tell me what's wrong / missing?

```
function isProductSelected(product, selectedproduct){
        $.each(selectedproduct,function(k,selectedproduct){
            if(product.id == selectedproduct.id){
                return true;
            }
        });
        return false;
}

profile+='<li class="list-group-item"><div class="checkbox">'
                                +'<label><input class="product '+i+'" type="checkbox" value="'+product.id+'" id="'+product.id+'"'+ ((isProductSelected(product,data.products) == true)?'checked':'')  +'> '+product.productName+'</label>'
                                +'</div></li>';
```

Answer (score 2):

Those are too many parenthesis. The following will work

```
(isProductSelected(product,data.products)  ? 'checked' : '')
```

Comment: Could also get rid of the `== true`

Comment: Also, if you find a place where  "c ? t: f" doesn't work, you can always do "c && t || f"

Comment: Problem was with isProductSelected implementation. It was always returning false.